# Trying to exclude field when persisting kotlin data class as document to Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: serialization, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data class

```
data class TripEntity(@Exclude val id: String = "", val name: String = "", val totalDistance: Long = 0, val startDate: Date?, val endDate: Date?)
```

Then I have these methods to persist the data

```
private fun writeNewTripEntity(tripEntity: TripEntity, emitter: ObservableEmitter<TripEntity>) {
    val tripCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users/test/trips");
    tripCollection.add(tripEntity).addOnSuccessListener({ documentReference ->
        onWriteEntitySuccess(documentReference, emitter, tripEntity)
    }).addOnFailureListener({ e ->
        onWriteEntityError(e, emitter)
    })
}

private fun onWriteEntitySuccess(documentReference: DocumentReference, emitter: ObservableEmitter<TripEntity>, tripEntity: TripEntity) {
    Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, "TripEntity saved to FireBase successfully: " + documentReference.toString())
    emitter.onNext(TripEntity(documentReference.id, tripEntity.name, tripEntity.totalDistance, tripEntity.startDate, tripEntity.endDate))
    emitter.onComplete()
}

private fun onWriteEntityError(e: Exception, emitter: ObservableEmitter<TripEntity>) {
    Timber.e("Data could not be saved: %s", e.message)
    emitter.onError(e)
}
```

The document is then persisted in Firestore but the ID is not excluded, as it should be according to Firestore documentation.

[image: Document screenshot]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to use @Transient for id

Comment: @fisher3421 Tried but the behaviour still remains the same.